# How to load a dependent dll into memory?

Tags: java, dll, dllimport, jna, dll-injection

I am using a dll into my Java Project. "mydll.dll" have dependencies such as:

```
C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_96748342450f6aa2\msvcm90d.dll

C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_96748342450f6aa2\MSVCR90D.dll

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll   

C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.9445_none_d08c58b4442ba54f\MSVCR80.dll

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\diasymreader.dll
```

Here is my problem: without installing vs2008, it gives error below even if the required dlls are exist in specified locations:

> The application has failed to start because the side by side
>   configuration is incorrect

I assumes that windows cant find required dll's in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs` so I'm seeking for advice to load those dependent dlls into memory before my project starts.

I've tried to install all vs environments. And my code which loads dll:

```
private SimpleDLL simpleDLL = SimpleDLL.INSTANCE;
static {
    System.loadLibrary("MyDll");
}
```

Comment: It is horribly messy.  At least "debugcrt" is a big problem, you need to ask whomever created the library to provide you with the Release build of the DLL.  If he doesn't provide you with an installer, like he should, then you can use the VS2008 C++ redist installer to get the runtime library you need.  You also need the VS2005 redist installer, .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.x.  Brr.  Do *not* use KnownDLLs.

Comment: I've installed both VS2008 C++ and VS2005 C++ packages and I've installed .net 2.0 - 3.5 - 4 also but without installing Visual Studio 2008 it never runs.
I "have to" load dependent dlls into memory before my program run.

Comment: What Hans is telling you is that the DLL you are loading cannot legally be redistrubuted. It is linked against debug versions of the runtime. Solve that by getting a replacement DLL that is linked against release versions of the runtime.

Comment: Thanks to both of you @DavidHeffernan and Hans Passant for helping. I got contact with the provider of dll.